# Possibility to return exception to a try block?

Tags: python, try-catch

I have a stupid qus. Still any alternate solution would be very helpful.

I have a try block in source which calls few functions.

```
def main(self):
    try:
        dict_1 = some_fun_a(self)
        dict_2 = some_fun_b(self)
        #some operations in dict
    except KeyError:
        #Raise some exception error.

def some_fun_a(self):
    try:
        #some validation regarding original data
    except ImportError:
        #Raise Exception
        return ImportError
```

I could inherit func_a/b & change logic as per req. However, when I face exception inside these functions, the main try block is still a success.

**QUS:**
Is there anyway I could return exception from some_fun_a() to main try block such that exception from main() is raised ?

Comment: It's very unclear what you're trying to accomplish here. You'll need to provide a clearer example and explanation.

Comment: Not return, but you can just re-throw it. Or throw another exception. Exactly like you tried, but commented-out.